# How to write throwing function inside throwing function such that both do/catch logic works?

Tags: ios, swift

Edit: What I am asking is if I want to write logic to both the catch block i.e one while calling throwingFunc1 and while calling throwingFunc2. How to do structure the code.

For example:

```
func throwingFunc1(_ par: Int) throws -> Int {
  do {
    let model = try throwingFunc2(par: "hello")
   } catch let err {
    print(err)
    // reaching here.
   }
 }

func throwingFunc2(par: String) throws -> Int {
    //return something
 }
```

Now what I want here is that, when I call throwingFunc1, inside a do-catch block, the catch block is not being called.
Something like this:

```
do {
   let m = throwingFunc1(2)
  } catch let error {
   //Not reaching here.
 }
```

How to structure this code such that both catch block is triggered in case throwingFunc2 sends error?

Comment: It's unclear what you want, but you could use `try?` (with a question mark) to ignore the error thrown?

Comment: Are you saying after you've handled the error you want to throw the error?

Comment: @Larme actually I have logic to write in both the catch block.

Comment: Yes @Shadowrun, can we do it ? Handling error of one throwing function then throwing it again to the caller function ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to re-throw the error if you want the caller to see it. Currently you're handling the error, so it is not re-thrown. To rethrow:

```swift
func throwingFunc1(_ par: Int) throws -> Int {
  do {
    let model = try throwingFunc2(par: "hello")
   } catch let err {
    print(err)
    throw err // <---- re-throw the error.
   }
 }
```

If you have no `catch` logic in `thowingFunc1`, you can remove the `do/catch`, and the `try` will throw to the caller automatically.

```swift
func throwingFunc1(_ par: Int) throws -> Int {
    let model = try throwingFunc2(par: "hello") // throws on failure
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can re-throw the error in the catch block in `throwingFunc1`:

```
func throwingFunc1(_ par: Int) throws -> Int {
    do {
        let model = try throwingFunc2(par: "hello")
    } catch let err {
        print(err)
        throw err
    }
}
```

Then the catch block of something like this would be executed:

```
do {
    let int = try throwingFunc1(1)
} catch {
    // ...
}
```

Note that the catch block pattern can be omitted:

```
catch {
    print(error)
    throw error
}
```